# How do you plot wiggle plots in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, plot

I am trying to plot magnetic data along a profile displayed on a map in QGIS 3.22.2.
This is a fairly common display type for geophysical data, but I can't find any examples for doing it in QGIS. This is the sort of thing I mean.  How do you do this in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: I'm not a geologist and I've never seen a map like this before so it would really help me if you could explain what we're looking at! I see variety of colors superimposed with wavy lines and some of the wavy lines have colored tips on them, but what does all this mean? Can you provide some examples of these data? As Dr. Evil once said, "Throw me a bone here!"

Comment: We are looking at a 2D magnetic profile, shown along the ship track where the profile was acquired superimposed on another grid. The challenge is to plot the magnetic profile with a field value plotted orthogonal to the profile, with some appropriate scaling applied.

Comment: Sure, I can see that, but what about your data?  You appear to have two types, vector (the wiggly lines) and raster (the colored background).  Please edit your original post to include detailed information about each.  Also... what have you tried so far, and what were the results?

Comment: The vector data is a simple x,y,field file. The raster data is irrelevant. It is only there because the example I found for the wiggle trace was overlaid on a raster image. The question is "is there a process already in QGIS which can plot the x,y,field profiles as a wiggle trace? ". thanks.

Comment: Once again.... what have you tried so far, and what were the results?

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far because I can't find an appropriate process. If it doesn't exist I will write one.

Comment: Great question and looking to do the same, for same reasons